# Is it possible to reduce test cases by taking expressions out from if statement?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, code-coverage

It might be a little silly question.
But I am contemplating this issue.

For example, if I extract test cases for below code
it will have 32 test cases to achieve 100% multiple condition coverage

```cpp
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) 
{
  if (a && b || c && d || e)
    return 100;
  else
    return 200;
}
```

An then if I change above code into below which need only 2 test cases to achieve 100% multiple condition coverage
In this case, can I say my test code achieve 100% multiple condition coverage?

```cpp
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) 
{
  bool cond = a && b || c && d || e;
  if (cond)
    return 100;
  else
    return 200;
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between the two. It's absolutely the same.

Comment: Firstly: I'd say both versions look identical to me both in terms of what assembler output I would expect from them as well as line and branch coverage. Both of them would require two test cases. I'm not familiar with condition coverage, but if one case requires 32 test cases, so should the other. In first case to determine branch, the other for determining value for cond.

Comment: You can remove your `if` with a `return 100*(1+cond)`, but I don't think that is a good idea because you hide the meaning of your code.